# How can I get a player's location and stock it in tree differents ints [Spigot 1.15.2]

Tags: plugins, minecraft

I want to create a command that gets the coordinates of the player who executed the command and stock it in three `int` (`X` `Y` `Z`) and to be able to use them in another command to teleport a player to those coordinates (it's a /spawn command).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `CommandExecutor`, explained over [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/create-a-simple-command/). You can get the [Location](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Location.html) fragments (X Y Z) from the [Location of the Player](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/entity/Entity.html#getLocation--). Then you need to save it somewhere to access it when the other command is executed, for example in a Hashmap to link the location to the player.

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (sender instanceof Player) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        // get location and location fragments
        Location loc = player.getLocation();

        double x = loc.getX();
        double y = loc.getY();
        double z = loc.getZ();
        // convert to int (information loss)
        int xInt = (int)x;
        int yInt = (int)y;
        int zInt = (int)z;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that when you cast to int that the coordinate resolves to the bttom-left position of the coordinate. This can be a problem due to suffocating if there is a tile occupied. Better off not casting to int.